# Can't style a td element

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why, but i can't seem to style a td element in my script. I'm trying to remove a border from all the td elements in the table-subtitles, and i guess my css is wrong somehow.

PS: I was able to remove the border by inline css only.

HTML:

```
<table> 
    <thead> 
        <tr>
            <th width="100%" colspan="5">My Recent Activity</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 
        <tr class="table-subtitles">
          <td style="border: 0"><h4>Date</h4></td>
          <td><h4>Description</h4></td>
          <td><h4>Amount</h4></td>
          <td><h4>Due</h4></td>
          <td><h4>Status</h4></td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($this->payments as $payment): ?>
        <tr>
        </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>        
        <?php 
            if ((count($this->payments)==0)) :
        ?>      
          <tr>
            <td style="border: 0; text-align: center" colspan="6" class="info">No payments made yet</td>
          </tr>
       <?php endif; ?>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
#payments-content { width: 480px; float: left; margin-right: 20px; }
#payments-sidebar { width: 270px; float: left; }

.ui-button-large .ui-button-large-text { font-size: 20px; width: 270px; }

// new tables design
.table-subtitles td{ border-bottom: 0 !important; }
```

Comment: try using firebug or chrome inspector to see the cascade of styles on the td. it's probably being replaces with some other rule with more precedence

Comment: Can you provide a complete, self-sufficient code sample that can be tested, i.e., in jsfiddle.net?

Comment: i just posted the full css file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

// is not a css comment. you must use /* */

Answer (score 1):

You might find want to make friends with `border-collapse` and `th`.

Comment: thanks, i'll google it a little. i don't like the border styling methods we're using now

Answer (score 1):

When I put just this table into a test HTML file I'm getting no borders by default. Therefore this is probably an inheritance issue with some previous table styling you have or are importing from your CSS. Normally, the solution to such problems is over riding whatever style its inheriting my making a more specific selector in CSS. So for example, give your table an ID and have your CSS style be:

```
#mytable .table-subtitles td { border-bottom: 0; }
```

Another great way to see exactly what's happening is to use Firebug in Firefox or the Chrome inspector see exactly what styles your table rows are picking up, inheriting or being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

did you try `border-bottom:0!important`

Comment: no, still doesn't work. strange. it looks like a really simple css issue and i can't seem to find the answer. i think it's the selector or something in main layout

Answer (score -4):

Your problem is with your selector.

Doing `.table-subtitles td` means: The TD element inside the element with the "table-subtitles" class.
What you need is:

`td.table-subtitles { border-bottom:0; }`

Comment: Exactly, that is what he's doing, his selector's fine.